# Discrepancy between two expected profit formulas

Tags: probability, expected-value, finance

I have two formulas for calculating the expected ratio of the account value after a trade to before it (we'll call this expected account ratio or EAR) that both make intuitive sense to me, yet they produce different results. The first formula uses the definition of expected value. The second uses a geometric mean. I'm unsure which accurately describes financial behavior and I'd like to understand which one is correct and why.

Terms: p is the probability of a trade winning with some profit before losing with probability 1-p with some loss. AB = available balance, or the amount in the account before the trade.

$$EAR1 = p \cdot \frac{AB + \text{profit}}{AB} + (1-p) \cdot \frac{AB + \text{loss}}{AB}$$
$$EAR2 = \left(\frac{AB + \text{profit}}{AB}\right)^p \left(\frac{AB + \text{loss}}{AB}\right)^{1-p}$$

The rationale for the first approach is that we calculate the actual EAR after a successful trade and weight it by p, and compute the actual EAR after a failed trade and weight it by 1-p. This in theory should give us the expected EAR after one trade.

The rationale for the second approach is as follows. Imagine that we make 2% per successful trade and lose 2% per failed trade. Since multiplication is commutative, the order in which wins and losses happen doesn't matter - just the totals of each. Assume p=0.6. Then if we take 10 trials, our expected EAR at the end of all 10 is 1.02^6 * 0.98^4. To find the per trade EAR, we take the 10th root of it. By the laws of exponents, this is equivalent to taking 1.02^0.6 * 0.98^0.4.

I can't figure out why the two approaches give different results other than putting them side by side and seeing that indeed they are not equal quantities since they cannot be made to cancel to zero. But both seem to describe a reasonable way of describing the behavior of an account after a trade. What am I missing?

Comment: If you take 10 trials, the expected EAR will be $$ \left[\left(1+\frac{\mathrm{profit}}{\mathit{AB}}\right)p + \left(1+\frac{\mathrm{loss}}{\mathit{AB}}\right)(1-p)\right]^{10}=\mathit{EAR1}^{10},$$ in light of the binomial distribution. I don't see how you ended up concluding "...if we take $10$ trials, our expected EAR at the end of all $10$ is $1.02^6 \cdot 0.98^4$".

Comment: @SangchulLee Your answer makes more sense than my original intuition; I concluded what I did by taking the probabilities of success and failure and applying them for 10 trials, but I can see that this doesn't actually constitute computing expectation. Can you expand on how this relates to the binomial distribution? Also, I am familiar with linearity of expectation in the additive context but it seems like you're applying a multiplicative equivalent by taking the EAR and exponentiating it.

Comment: If we let $N$ the number of wins in the 10 trials, then the account ratio will be a function of $N$ given by:$$f(N)=\left(1+\frac{\mathrm{profit}}{\mathit{AB}}\right)^N \left(1+\frac{\mathrm{loss}}{\mathit{AB}}\right)^{10-N}.$$ Now, for each $n$, there are total $\binom{10}{n}$ possible ways that results in $N=n$, and each such way results in AR of $f(n)$. So, $$\mathit{EAR}=\mathbb{E}[f(N)]=\sum_{n=0}^{10}\binom{10}{n}f(n)p^n(1-p)^{10-n},$$ and this reduces to $\mathit{EAR1}^{10}$ by invoking the binomial theorem.

Comment: Alternatively, let $X_0=\mathit{AB}$ denote the initial balance, and let $X_k$ denote the balance after $k$ trials. Then the annual AR, $Z_k:=X_k/X_{k-1}$, $k=1,\ldots,10$, are independent and governed by the same law: $$Z_k=\begin{cases}1+\mathrm{profit}/\mathrm{AB},&\text{with probability }p\\1+\mathrm{loss}/\mathrm{AB},&\text{with probability }1-p\end{cases}$$ Then $X_{10}/X_0=Z_1\cdots Z_{10}$, and by the independence, $$\mathit{EAR}=\mathbb{E}[X_{10}/X_0]=\mathbb{E}[Z_1\cdots Z_{10}]=\mathbb{E}[Z_1]\cdots\mathbb{E}[Z_{10}]=\mathit{EAR1}^{10}.$$

Comment: Your second explanation is excellent. Thank you very much.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thank you also for your first answer. Modeling $N$ as a binomial random variable and taking the expectation of a function of it is a beautiful approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$EAR2$ is the correct formula because taking the expectation of a binomial random variable assumes independence of trials, which is not the case in any context that involves compounding, such as this question's context of trading. Binomial expectation relies on each outcome contributing equally and independently to the overall outcome. Since a 2% win following a 2% produces a greater than 2% win on top of the original available balance, the binomial model fails and we must use the geometric mean instead.

Comment: The binomial model and the geometric mean are correct.

Answer (score 2):

If the increasing rate and decreasing rate are $2\%$ then your factors $1.02$ and $0.98$ are right. If you have $n$ trials, then you have $\binom{n}{x}$ ways of  making $x$ times profit and $n-x$ times making loss. The probability of making profit is $p$ and therefore the probability of making loss is $1-p$

Then the probability of making profit $x$ times and making $n-x$ times loss (in exactly that order) is $p^x\cdot (1-p)^{n-x}$.

The outcome after   making profit $x$ and making $n-x$ times loss (in exactly that order) is $1.02^x\cdot 0.98^{n-x}$

The number of ways making profit $x$ times and making $n-x$ times loss is $\binom{n}x$. Let $EAR$ be the expected account ratio. If $EAR=1$, the winning/loosing is $0$

Then $(EAR)^n$ after $n$ trials is

$$(EAR)^n=\sum\limits_{x=0}^n \binom{n}x 1.02^x\cdot 0.98^{n-x}\cdot p^x\cdot (1-p)^{n-x}$$

$$=\sum\limits_{x=0}^n \binom{n}x (1.02p)^x\cdot (0.98\cdot (1-p))^{n-x}$$

The binomial theorem is $ (a+b)^n=\sum\limits_{x=0}^{n}{{n \choose x}\cdot a^{x}\cdot b^{n-x}} $. If we apply that we get

$$(EAR)^n=(1.02p+0.98\cdot (1-p))^n$$

Now we calculate $EAR$ by using the geometric mean

$$EAR=1.02p+0.98\cdot (1-p)$$

If $p=0.5$, then $EAR=1$. This is not surprisingly, since the possible amounts of winning and loosing are equal at a given level.

Comment: E(p) isn't the term you're looking for in your first line of math. p is the probability of a win - a constant. You want the EAR.

Comment: Here's an issue regarding your last line. Your math is correct, but if you have a trading strategy which wins and loses 2% again and again, you will end up with zero over time. How do we reconcile this with the result of the expected value calculation which suggests that we should remain at a constant account value forever? 1.02*0.98 = 0.9996, which implies that if you repeat this ad infinitum you end up with no money.

Comment: Yes, you're right, that I was not precise. It is $(1+EAR)^n$

Comment: It's just EAR, not 1 + EAR. EAR is the ratio of the account value after the trade to before it, not the expected profit percentage.

Comment: Ok, I'm not familiär wird these terms  (im english). // Let's say you have one step with an initial value C, then the expected amount is $C*0.5*1.02+C*0.98*0.5=C$. So your profit/loss is $0$. Your have to regard all ways and not only one way.

Comment: @SangchulLee do you have any input on this? Why is it that it is a mathematical fact that even with a zero expectation you always lose everything? Does it have to do with the Markov chain model of the Gambler's ruin problem?

Comment: @NursultanTulyakbay I've made an edit by using EAR. //The concept is just the expected value. You have two possible outcomes, one with prob. p and the other with prob. (1-p). So you can calculate the expected value after one step or after $n$ steps.

Comment: @SangchulLee If you have a moment, please take a look at this post. https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/73511/expected-account-ratio-versus-actual-financial-behavior.

Comment: @NursultanTulyakbay I've seen it. My question is: What do you mean by "real financial behaviour"? If you can assume   that the conditions for a binomial model are fulfilled, then you use the method above. If not, you have to use another model/method.

Comment: I mean the binomial model predicts that the account value doesn't change over time if you use the expected value calculation given by $EAR1$. Instead, as shown in the post, if you take any percent loss and percent gain over and over again with exactly half probability each, you are guaranteed to reach zero.

Comment: I think I understand your point. If we calculate just one increasing and one decreasing then inddeed the result is lower than the initial value. $x*(1+r)*(1-r)=x*(1-r^2)<1$. But this is only one of 4 paths. We have 4 paths, if we calculate the expected value: 1. Up-Up, 2. Up-Down, 3. Down-Up, 4. Down-Down. If p=0.5 all paths are equal propable. Then the expected value of 2. and 3. Is less than x. But the expected value of 1. and 4. more than x. At 4. we have the effect, that a value increases more, the higher the value is. So after the value of value after the first growth is $x*(1+r)$.

Comment: @NursultanTulyakbay (continued) From this higher level the increasing gets bigger, since the base is larger than x. So case 4. can compensate the cases 1., 2. and 3. If you want a longer answer then ask this question on MSE.

Comment: @NursultanTulyakbay If you want a longer answer then ask this quite interesting question on MSE. I have some flaws in my two previous comments. But the content itself should be O..K. Sorry for that. I'm writing with my smartphone.

Comment: I see that all four paths are equally probable and your expectation calculation is correct. If we run a simulation would it turn out like this? The point I wish to make here is that if p is indeed 0.5, over a long enough number of trials we can assume the number of wins is 50% of the total and if we do that we are guaranteed to lose everything, so the expectation calculation suggests we would break even over the long run but in practice we lose everything consistently, every single time.

Comment: In any case, I believe the reason the geometric mean is the correct approach here is that as suggested in this thread, stock returns accumulate via multiplications, not additions.

https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/965/how-does-return-based-analysis-calculate-expected-return-of-a-trading-system?rq=1

Also see the link below:

https://www.wallstreetmojo.com/geometric-mean-vs-arithmetic-mean/#:~:text=The%20geometric%20mean%20is%20always,calculated%20as%20a%20simple%20average.&text=It%20is%20applicable%20only%20to,and%20negative%20sets%20of%20numbers.

Comment: @SangchulLee Update: I figured out exactly why the geometric mean is the correct approach. Taking the expectation of a binomial random variable assumes each trial is independent, which they are NOT if the effects are compounding. If you make 2% on top of 2%, that second 2% is a larger raw return, whereas the binomial model assumes they add linearly.